# Unable to Update remainingClicks State after Incrementing User Clicks in React Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, google-cloud-functions

I have an asynchronous function callCreateCountIfPassedClicks that performs several operations, including fetching user clicks data, making an API call to a cloud function, and incrementing user clicks. At the end of these operations, I want to update the remainingClicks state using the setRemainingClicks function. However, when I try to set the remainingClicks, it doesn't seem to work. I have the following code snippet:

here is my Authcontext code im sharing state here

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { app } from '../../firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'

export const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null) // current connected user, if null it means the user trying to access app is not authed
  const [accountLinked, setAccountLinked] = useState(false)
  const [remainingClicks, setRemainingClicks] = useState(null)
  const [timeUntilReset, setTimeUntilReset] = useState(null)
  const getUserClicksData = firebase.app().functions('europe-west3').httpsCallable('clicks-getUserClicksData')

  const fetchData = async () => {

    try {
      const result = await getUserClicksData()
      const { data } = result
      setTimeUntilReset(data.timeUntilReset)
      setRemainingClicks(data.remainingClicks)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw error // Re-throw the error to be caught by the calling function
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("fetch data has been used")
    }
  }, [fetchData])

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscribe
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const { uid } = user
        subscribe = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).onSnapshot(snapshot => { // find the profile associated to the connected user => the {user}.id === {current connected user}.uid (firebase authentication)
          if (snapshot.exists) {
            setCurrentUser({ ...snapshot.data(), firebaseUser: { ...user } })
          } else {
            setCurrentUser(null)
          }
        })
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null)
      }
    })
    return () => {
      if (subscribe) { // close snapshot listenner to avoid breaking free quotas
        subscribe()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, accountLinked, setAccountLinked, timeUntilReset, setTimeUntilReset, remainingClicks, setRemainingClicks, fetchData }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
    const callCreateCountIfPassedClicks = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            if (!currentUser || !currentUser.user_id) {
                throw new Error('Current user not found')
            }

            // Fetch user clicks data
            const userClicksDataResult = await getUserClicksData_()
            const remainingClicks = userClicksDataResult.data.remainingClicks
            const timeUntilReset = userClicksDataResult.data.timeUntilReset

            if (remainingClicks <= 0) {
                if (timeUntilReset > 0) {
                    lunchErrorToast(`Limite de clics atteinte, veuillez réessayer dans ${timeUntilReset} Minute${timeUntilReset > 1 ? "s" : ""}`, "danger")
                    return
                }
            }

            // Making the API call to the cloud function
            const response = await createCount({ query: queryObject, selectedCriteria })

            // Check if the count returned a valid value
            if (response && response.data) {
                // Increment user clicks
                await incrementUserClicks_()
                // bug here cannot set the remainig clicks 
                // setRemainingClicks(resp.data.remainingClicks)
                // Fetch the updated data after incrementing
                // Depending on the type of the response, we update the UI in different ways
                if (typeof response.data === "object" && !Array.isArray(response.data)) {
                    setMultipleRes(response.data)
                    setIsShowBtnSection(true)
                } else if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
                    history.push({ pathname: "/pages/free/count_criteria/b2c", state: { resultQueryArray: response.data, selectedCriteria, queryObject } })
                } else {
                    setResultQuery(response.data)
                    setIsShowBtnSection(true)
                    setMultipleRes([])
                }
                
            } else {
                throw new Error('Count did not return a valid value')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            handleError(error)
        } finally {
            console.log("here")
            await fetchData()
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
```

The fetchData function inside the AuthProvider is supposed to update the remainingClicks and timeUntilReset state after fetching from a Firebase Cloud Function. But, the state doesn't seem to reflect the updated values.

After the incrementUserClicks_ function call, I expected the remainingClicks state to be decremented. However, when I call the fetchData function to refresh the state with updated data from the backend, the state momentarily updates and then reverts to its initial value.

I've even checked the AuthProvider and ensured that fetchData sets the state correctly. But still, the state doesn't seem to persist its updated value in my component.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong and how to correctly update and persist the state?